# How to write optimized logic in C to reduce loop?

Tags: c, pointers, memory

I have the following code snippet,

```
int main()
{
    int loop;
    
    char * src = 0x20000000;
    char * dest = 0x20000008;

    for(loop = 0; loop < 8; loop++)
       dest [loop] = src [loop];
}
```

Is this a valid code?  How to optimize the logic to reduce looping?

Comment: Usually the best way is to just call `memcpy`, which has already been optimized by people much smarter than any of us :-)

Comment: have you tried it with your compiler and see what it says about this `char * src = 0x20000000;` ? Do that first before worrying about the the loop logic.

Comment: A very permissive but otherwise optimizing compiler would be allowed to replace the entire code with just `int main() { return 0; }` which is hard to beat performance wise ;-)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Specifically to the above point, `warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast char * src = 0x20000000;`. What's the point of the code here?

Comment: **Are you sure that `0x20000000` is a *valid* address?** On my Debian x86-64 desktop, **it is not,** because of [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASLR). Consider reading [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/) then the documentation of your C compiler (e.g. [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)..), your debugger (e.g. [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/), ...) and perhaps your operating system...

Comment: **Did you try your program?** Did you read the C11 standard [n1570](https://web.cs.dal.ca/~vlado/pl/C_Standard_2011-n1570.pdf) ? I am not sure your program is illegal, but it smells badly having some **[undefined behavior](https://blog.llvm.org/posts/2011-05-13-what-every-c-programmer-should-know/)**

Comment: **My belief is that your understanding about direct assignment of memory address is wrong.** For example, the [Linux kernel](http://kernel.org/) has *lots* of such assignments.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, I understand that direct assignment of memory address (like 0x20000000) without addressing to a variable is not allowed by the compiler. This code snippet is just an indication. I'm mainly bothering about the loop and it's optimization. Thank you.

Comment: **Trust your optimizing compiler** it will generate better code that what you can write. Read about [MILEPOST GCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MILEPOST_GCC). **Without improvements, your question is unclear**. Please refer to [this website about C](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c). Think of coding for a [RaspBerryPi](http://raspberrypi.org/)

Comment: Regarding performance! **Do benchmark** On most computers (e.g. a modern laptop in 2020) your code would run in less than one µs. Please explain in written English why one microsecond is important to you. Explain what kind of applications are you coding! Is it some nuclear missile embedded software? Is it some high-frequency trading? You need to mention your application domain in your question !

Comment: Even if your code is driving some machine gun, in one microsecond a bullet travels less than 20cm. The time spent in [crt0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crt0) is much more than a microsecond. Or are you working at [CERN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CERN) on some accelerator like [LHC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_Hadron_Collider)? That is the only context where I would imagine a microsecond matters, and if you work there you need to talk to senior experts.

Comment: So without additional context, **your question makes no sense**. Any good optimizing compiler would generate good enough code. With [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compile with `gcc -O3 -fverbose-asm -S` then look into the generated assembler. Also, your development costs are worth much more than a microsecond, even scaled to a million instances.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Shooting bullet is a rather weird example of situation where 1µs  matters. There are a lot of casual scenarios where it can be critical. Consider for example graphics or networking software - if you stall every packet by 1µs, it will have drastic negative effect on overall performance.

Comment: @SomeWittyUsername: we both agree. The OP (Das Krishna) should provide more context and motivation in his/her question. Feel free to vote "close" as I did.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the compiler doesn't do it automatically, it can be optimized if there a couple of assumptions in place:

- Size of `char` is 1 byte
- The CPU instruction set supports 8-byte operations (for non-64-bit platforms the implementation may vary)

1. Cast (or directly define) the source and destination addresses to `unsigned long long*`
2. Perform direct assignment from source to destination. If the platform instruction set supports 64-bit operations, it should result in copy of 64-bit data chunk from source to destination. E.g., on Intel CPUs it can be done with a single `movsq` assembly instruction.

   ```
   int main()
   {
        unsigned long long * src = 0x20000000;
        unsigned long long * dest = 0x20000008;

        *dest = *src;

        return 0;
    }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

> Is this a valid code?

You can use your compiler to find that out.  The loop part in particular is valid code, which I suppose is what you're really asking about.

> How to optimize the logic to reduce looping?

Turn on optimization in your compiler, it will take care of the rest.  There's no way to improve on that code from a performance perspective, though you could use `memcpy()` to make the code more concise and easier to read.